# Questions about skeptical methodology

Tags: discussion

Are questions relating to how to go about figuring out some piece of information allowed on the skeptics site? I tend to get the feeling that only questions can be debunked seem to be allowed. However I feel like it would also help the cause in allowing questions that explain how one goes about finding reliable information. For example:

How can one find out if a medical treatment is effective?

That might be a little too broad but the general idea is that one would explain what to look for in detecting potential scam treatments, list reliable websites, etc.

What do you guys think of such questions.

Answer (score 2):

Such questions are off-topic as per our [FAQ](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq):

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Skeptics - Stack Exchange is for skeptics, rationalists, free thinkers, or anyone who questions pseudoscience. Skeptics is about applying skepticism — it's for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. **It is not for philosophical discussions about skepticism itself.**

You can also find more about on- and off- topic questions (and the relative community discussions) here in the meta site.

Comment: I am under impression the asker has in mind real practical advices on how to apply skepticism in real life situations. Not some philosophical discussion about skepticism itself. Not sure maybe that's offtopic too...

Comment: I think such questions might be more appropriate for meta, actually, since they are about how to answer questions?

Comment: Example: situation is this and this, claim is this and this, what test could verify the claim in the situation? Or: situation is like this, claim is like this, I came up with test like this. Please tell me if the test is fine. That's how I understand the original question, maybe I am wrong. In any case I'd still be interested if applied skepticism questions are on topic here ;) )

Comment: @Sejanus Your examples are on topic - the difference is that the answers will be discussing a specific claim, and not a broad methodology question.